# Linux Bash pass function argument to array name

Tags: arrays, bash, function, arguments

I'm working on a script that has a number of functions in place which pull data from a few different arrays. We hope to keep the arrays individualized for reporting purposes. The information in the arrays does not change and the only thing different between each function is which array name is being used. Since all of the functions have 98% the same content I'm trying to pull them into 1 single array for simplified management.

The issue I'm facing though is that I'm not able to figure out the correct syntax to obtain the length of an array based on the array title that is passed in the function argument. I can't post the actual script, but here is a mock up that details a simplified version of what I'm testing with. I believe if we can get it working using the mock script below I can transfer the needed changes to the actual script.

```
array1=(
    "item1 123"
    "item2 456"
)

array2=(
    "stockA qwe"
    "stockB asd"
    "stockC zxc"
)

test() {
     local ref=${1}[@]
     IFS=$'\n'; for i in ${!ref}; do echo $i ; done
}

test array1
test array2
```

The script above so far will echo the content of each array line based on argument 1 when the function and it's argument is called; which is working as needed. I've tried many different combinations such as `len=${#${1}[@]}` but I always receive a "bad substitution" error. The functions I mention before have while loops and for statements that use the array length to know when to stop, so being able to pull that information really ties it all together. What I'm hoping for is something like the flow below

I plan to continue my research on this, but thank you for any help and knowledge that can be provided!

-Cyanide

Comment: Quote `${!ref}`, and you won't have to change the value `IFS`: `for i in "${!ref}"; do`

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solution is to create a copy of the array, then take the length of that array:

```
local ref=${1}[@]
copy=( "${!ref}" )
len=${#copy[@]}
```

Since `bash` does not allow chaining of the parameter expansion operators, I know of no shorter way to use both `${#...}` and `${!...}` on the same line.